# BouncyCastle, how long should it take to generate a RSA keypair?

Tags: c#, vb.net, bouncycastle

I'm using Bouncy Castle (c#/vb.net version) and generating a 4096-byte RSA Keypair to use in my certificate with this routine:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateRSAKeypair(keylength As Integer) As AsymmetricCipherKeyPair
    Dim r As New RsaKeyPairGenerator()
    r.Init(New KeyGenerationParameters(New SecureRandom(), keylength))
    Dim keys As AsymmetricCipherKeyPair = r.GenerateKeyPair()
    Return keys
End Function
```

The procedure works ok, however it takes a very long time, up to one minute (I'm on a 2.4ghz pentium DualCore).

Since I don't have much experience (almost none really) with RSA and all these things, I just wanted to ask if it's normal that it takes so long to generate the key, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code looks similar to the key generation seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844997/encrypting-a-bouncycastle-rsa-key-pair-and-storing-in-a-sql2008-database as such I suspect that is as long as it takes. Have you profiled the steps to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: Yeah, I had taken the code from there :D Guess there's no solution other than waiting... probably I'll invoke the method asynchronously then, else my UI freezes for one minute... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some theory about RSA, I can confirm there's nothing wrong with the code, it simply takes that long to generate such a big key.